# UIScrollView horizontal scroll not working

Tags: ios5, ios6, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate, contentsize

I have the following setup:

On top of a `UIViewController` I've set a `UIScrollView` with size 320 x 56. Inside the UIScrollView I have a UIView with size 640 x 56. The UIScrollView has the autoresize prop uncheked and it's scrollable horizontally only..

So in the `viewDidLoad` method I set the contentSize to the IOutlet of the `UIScrollView`. I set it as 640 x 56. Also the delegate to the UIScrollView is set in this method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(640, 56);
}
```

The problem is that I can't get the control to scroll. Also I nslog the bounds and frame of the `UIScrollView` and `UIView` and both are set to 0,0 when the methods `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` are called. Not sure what I'm missing here.

The idea is to be able to have the `UIView` scroll to the sides and show the controls that are embedded.

I've tried many suggestions found in diff post and can't make this to work. Help is appreciated!!!

Thanks

Comment: are you creating the scrollView in the Interface builder? If so, do you have the IBOutlet connected to your NIB?

Comment: IBOulet is connected, yes. I have an IBOulet for the UIScrollView and one for the IUView. For the IUView I just wanted to nslog its properties.

Comment: can you post here nslogs for the scrollview size, view size and scrollview content offset ... get the values on viewDidAppear

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by unchecking the Autolayout option. Also the contentSize was the only property for the scrollView set in the viewDidLoad.

Thanks